# How (in what order) WebSocket handles requests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

Is WebSocketHandler in Spring multi-threaded?
When WebSocketHandler receives multiple requests, does Spring allocate several threads to handle them, by calling handleTextMessage() in WebSocketHandler. Or are the incoming requests handled 1 by 1, in sequential order?

Answer (score 0):

Spring by default is multi threaded. For restful controllers, each new connection is put in a new thread. Each new websocket connection is simply an enhanced restful connection and should follow the same process.